# Adding a column for UTF-8 content in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl

Anybody has ideas, how to add a column meant for storing UTF-8 content in MySQL?

I tried the following:

```
ALTER TABLE tname ADD COLUMN cname TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci IF NOT EXISTS;
```

That gives an error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'if not exists' at line 1

I want to add a new *column* with UTF-8 encoding.

Thanks.

Comment: That error should give you what you need to find your answer.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score 8):

This is not a valid syntax for [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html).

Here is the correct way:

```
ALTER TABLE tname ADD COLUMN cname TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

While specifying the collation to the table you have been careful about the table.

```
alter table table_name add column column_name text character set utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL comment 'Comment to the attachment file';
```